# How to get the average CPU and memory usage of an android application from the Android Monitor in Android Studio?

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, adb, ddms

How to derive the average CPU and memory of an android application from the Android Monitor ?

https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-monitor.html

I can't find any options where I can get the raw values of the cpu and memory monitor so I can average them over a specific time.

For example, how can access the values of this CPU graph and average them, lets for ten minutes?
https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-cpu.html

Update:

AS @Pein suggested, I checked these usages in the system information of Android Device Monitor. However, now there are two CPU usages for each process such as user and kernal. My understanding is that these two usages are not occurring at the same time which means the actual cpu usage should be an average of these two. For example, the cpu usage of my app in user mode is shown as 9% and in kernel mode as 3%. So let me summarize the questions again.

1. Now is the actual CPU usage 6% such that (3+9)/3 or 12% (9+3) ?
2. Are these values instantaneous or average over time ?
3. I still can't see a clear number for memory usage of the app in system information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Device monitor check System information tab.
There you can find memory usage and cpu usage
Also you can select your process and start profiling in order to check how much time takes your methods